# Array not dynamically updating due to mis-use of states

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, state

When a radio button is clicked it changes a value from 0 to 1 or vice versa.
This is done through 2 components Test.js and Graph_Test.js.
Test.js is where the radio buttons are created and the array is filled. E.g when radio button 1 is pressed, I want it to change the value in array[1] from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.
So any time a radio button is pressed it will dynmaically change the array.
This array is then used to build a graph in Graph_Test.js, depending on which indexes have 1 values beside it will make corresponding lines on the graph.
For example if array = [0,1,0,0] , a line will be drawn for region 1.
So as this array dynamically changes so will the lines on the graph.

I am testing my code. In Graph_test I've it outputting array[0] and when a radio button[0] is touched this value should update. However this is not happening.

In test.js, i've used states this is where my problem is as the inital array is being dleivered as a prop but it is not dynamically updating.

Graph_test.js has two props which is sent through array and testing, testing will be used to build the graph later on . But is not currently needed.

Ive tried many attempts, and still not getting anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated/needed.

Code:
Test.js:

```
// When radio buttons checked, change corresponding value in array if 0 change to 1 and if 1 change to 0
// This will be used in the graph component, and will enable the functionality of selcting one region or multiple region.
// As the graph will be plotted based on which regions are noted 1 in the array 
import $ from "jquery";
import Graph_Test from "./Graph_Test.js";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const Test = props => {
  const total_regions = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.test)).length); // gets the number of regions
  const [array, setArray] = useState(Array(total_regions.length).fill(0));
    //when a radio button is clicked change its corresponding in the array

//when a radio button is clicked change its corresponding in the array
const handleClick = (item, idx) => {
  if (array[idx] == 1) {
    array[idx] = 0;
  } else {
    array[idx] = 1;
  }
  setArray(array);
};

  return (   // displays radio buttons depending on the number of objects in json
    <div>
      <div>
        <Graph_Test  testing={[]} arrays={array}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        {props.test.map((item, idx) => { 
          return (
            <label key={idx}>
              <input className="region" type="radio" value={idx} onClick={() => handleClick(item, idx)}/>
              <span>{idx}</span> 
            </label>
          );
        })}  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Graph_Test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
//<h1>{props.testing.map}</h1>
const Graph_Test = props => { 

    return(
      <div>
        <div>
        {props.arrays && props.arrays.length > 0 && <p>{props.arrays[0]}</p> }
        </div>     
      </div >
    );
  };export default Graph_Test;
```

App.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import LeftPane from "./components/LeftPane.js";
import Video from "./components/Video.js";
//import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import Test from "./components/Test.js";
import Graph_Test from "./components/Graph_Test.js";
//import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: [] };
    this.state = {
      clicked: "no"
    };
  }
  // Comunicate with API
  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/IntensityAPI") //React app talks to API at this url
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }
  handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, isClicked: "yes" });
  console.log("clicked");
};
  componentWillMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div class="row fixed-top fixed-bottom no-gutters"  >
            <div class="col-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom">
              <LeftPane></LeftPane>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom" >
              <Video></Video>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-3 fixed-bottom">
            <Test test = {this.state.apiResponse} handler={this.handleClick}/>
            <Graph_Test testing = {this.state.apiResponse} arrays={[]}  {...this.state}/>

            </div>      
            </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
//  <Footer test = {this.state.apiResponse}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK React does not perform deep comparison with the state, so since you're reusing the already existing array it has the same memory reference as the previous one.

Try something like this:

```
const handleClick = (item, idx) => {
  const newArray = [...array]
  if (newArray[idx] == 1) {
    newArray[idx] = 0;
  } else {
    newArray[idx] = 1;
  }
  setArray(newArray);
};
```